# How to name a column " " in officer was able to do it previously in ReporteRs

Tags: r, flextable, officer

this is a big problem for me as I need to have un-named column names inside my flextable in officer. This previously worked with the ReporteRs version.
But so far haven't been able to do this, tried using the following code:

```
rename(` ` = col0)
```

When I run try and create a flextable using this column name I get the following error message:
Error in flextable(a) :
   invalid col_keys, flextable support only syntactic names

```
data <- head(iris) %>%
  rename(` ` = Sepal.Length)
myft <- regulartable(data)
myft1<- flextable(data)
```

Note: the regulartable(data) works and the column name is blank.
When trying to do this with a flextable however it doesn't work and errors

Is there anyway that I am able to do this with a flextable?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: edited post - regular table works but flextable doesn't and i'd like it to work with flextable too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to modify your data.frame to customize the display. Having names like  is risky IHMO. Read https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/layout.html#manage-headers-and-footers

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

data <- head(iris)
myft <- regulartable(data) %>% 
  set_header_labels(Sepal.Length = " ")

myft1 <- flextable(data) %>% 
  set_header_labels(Sepal.Length = " ")

myft1
```

Comment: Thanks very much :)